# Flash Attribute in custom AuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

On login failure I want to redirect the user to an error page and display a meaningful error message. Is it possible to add Flash Attributes that will be passed to the subsequent request?

The code presented below doesn't work. `RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap()` returns `null`.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
        if (outputFlashMap != null)
        {
            outputFlashMap.put("error", "Error message");
        }
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess it's null because you are calling the function from the filter chain, whereas the flash map is maintained by Spring's `DispatcherServlet` which the request hasn't passed through at this point.

Why not just use a parameter? i.e

```
 response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/error?error=" + "Error Message");
```

Comment: If there is no other option, it's doable, however I prefer not to disclose my parameters in query string.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this same problem with Spring 4.3.17 and finally found a solution by stepping through the spring-webmvc code and making educated guesses about how to integrate Flash Attributes outside the normal framework. [SessionFlashMapManager](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.17.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/SessionFlashMapManager.html) is the key to getting this to work. I believe this method should work for Spring 3.1.1+.

```
package org.myorg.spring.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMap;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager;

@Component
public final class FlashAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    /**
     * Flash attribute name to save on redirect.
     */
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_MESSAGE = "FLASH_AUTHENTICATION_MESSAGE";

    public FlashAuthenticationFailureHandler()
    {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if (exception != null)
        {
            final FlashMap flashMap = new FlashMap();
            // Don't send the AuthenticationException object itself because it has no default constructor and cannot be re-instantiated.
            flashMap.put(AUTHENTICATION_MESSAGE, exception.getMessage());
            final FlashMapManager flashMapManager = new SessionFlashMapManager();
            flashMapManager.saveOutputFlashMap(flashMap, request, response);
        }
        response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
        return;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller(s) that requires the flash attribute, simply add a ModelAttribute with the same name:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/someview"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSomePage(final Authentication authentication, @ModelAttribute(FlashAuthenticationFailureHandler.AUTHENTICATION_MESSAGE) final String authenticationMessage, final Model model) throws Exception
{
    if (authenticationMessage != null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("loginMessage", authenticationMessage);
    }

    return "myviewname";
}
```

Then the page attribute containing the message can be accessed in your JSP as follows:

```
<c:if test="${not empty loginMessage}">
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><c:out value="${loginMessage}" /></div>
</c:if>
```