# Add flash attribute to logout in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security, and I would like to add a flash attribute to the automatic redirect to the login page. However, the `handle` method of the `LogoutSuccessHandler` only has `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, `Authentication` as parameters. How can I retrieve the `RedirectAttributes` within the `handle` method in order to add flash attributes? Or is there an other way to add to flash attributes to the logout redirect?

Comment: The RedirectAttributes are the default/recommended way of adding a flash attribute (see the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-flash-attributes).

Comment: @dur Thank you very much, I overlooked that. I tried to retrieve the outputFlashMap as well as the flashMapManager from within the LogoutSuccessHandler, but `RequestContextUtils.getFlashMapManager` and `RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap` both return null.

Comment: @dur I tried it with the LogoutHandler, but with the same result (i.e. both methods return null). Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: Rolch2015 did you found answer ? I have got same problem with flash messages?

Comment: @carousel Unfortunately not, I tried to find a solution for quite some time before writing this question, and gave up ever since, because there were things of higher priority. Maybe I will look at it at some point later in time and will post the solution here, if I find one. However, if you find a solution, I would also be interested to know it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the following code worked:

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final FlashMap flashMap = new FlashMap();
        flashMap.put("information", "You've been logged out.");
        final FlashMapManager flashMapManager = new SessionFlashMapManager();
        flashMapManager.saveOutputFlashMap(flashMap, request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("/"); // or any other location you want
        super.handle(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Inspiration was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50429613/4751173) by user @vallismortis.

Comment: Thank you, finally had the chance to test it - it worked. Probably noteworthy: the custom logout success handler has to be registered, e.g. in the `HttpSecurity` filter chain like this: `httpSecurity.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)`.